# DDlog symbol duplication xcode

Tags: xcode, build-error, duplicate-symbol

I am trying to add Lumberjack logger to my project. However it seems that a precompiled library in the project also has this included in it so I get a lot of duplicate symbol errors:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_DDAbstractLogger in:
    /Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj-convqcjaldtjprauqzfewmacvahe/Build/Intermediates/proj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MVP3.1_iPhone.build/Objects-normal/i386/DDLog.o
    /Users/developer/Documents/work/proj/Common/Authentec/DownloadableAgentLib/libDownloadableAgent.a(DDLog.o)
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Not quite an Xcode question (this is a problem with the setup of the linker, not with the IDE). However, it seems that you added to your project both a static library **and** the to-be-compiled implementation files.

Comment: One of the static libraries I use has this (lumberjack) in it. It's a precompiled lib so I can't change it. What is a workaround for this issue? (I need to keep that lib and also add the logging library to the rest of the project)

Comment: Use the `ar` tool to remove the extraneous object files from the static library.

Comment: can't remove them, ... any other suggestions

Comment: @userXXX Why exactly can't you remove them? You surely can. No other suggestions. (or maybe exclude the appropriate source files from tue compilation, not sure if that woild break anything.)

Comment: It's a external DRM library... management doesn't want it modified